# uncaught references error not define

Tags: javascript

I came across a problem with javascript, it keeps on coming with a uncaught reference error: voeruit not define.

It's a different language, because i'm dutch.

I hope that somebody will spot the problem, I'm just starting so I need to learn what to do with these kind of problems

```js
 function reset()
      {      
      var fout1object = document.getElementById('fout1').innerHTML;
      var fout2object = document.getElementById('fout2').innerHTML;
      var fout3object = document.getElementById('fout3').innerHTML;
      var foutje = false
      fout1object = "";
      fout2object = "";
      fout3object = "";
      }
      function foutcontrole1(foutje)  
      {                   
         var invoer = Number(document.getElementById('invoer1').value);
         var datum = new Date();

         var foutobject = document.getElementById('fout1').innerHTML;
         
         var jaar = datum.getFullYear();
         
         if( isNaN(invoer) )
         {
          foutobject ="moet getal zijn"
          document.getElementById("fout1").innerHTML = foutobject;         
          foutje = true; 
         }
          else
         {
          if(invoer < 1911)
          {
            foutobject ="Bouwjaar moet boven 1910 zijn";
            document.getElementById("fout1").innerHTML = foutobject;
            foutje = true; 
          }
          else
          {
           if(invoer >= jaar)
           {
            foutobject ="Jaartal moet lager zijn dan of gelijk aan " + datum.getFullYear();
            document.getElementById("fout1").innerHTML = foutobject;
                  foutje = true; 
           }
          }
         }
         
         function foutcontrole2(foutje)
         {
        
         var invoer = Number(document.getElementById('invoer2').value);
         var foutobject = document.getElementById('fout2').innerHTML;
        
         if( isNaN(invoer) )
         {
          foutobject ="moet een getal zijn";
          document.getElementById("fout2").innerHTML = foutobject;
          foutje = true; 
         }
         else
         {
          if(invoer < 1000)
          {
            foutobject="De nieuwprijs moet minimaal 1000 euro zijn";
            document.getElementById("fout2").innerHTML = foutobject;
            foutje = true; 
          }
         }
         }
        
         function berekenen()
         {
          uitkomst = 100;
          window.alert(uitkomst)
         }
          
        
     
      
      function voeruit()
      {
       var foutje = false;
       reset();
       foutcontrole1(foutje);
       foutcontrole2(foutje);
      
       if( !foutje )
       {
       berkenen(); 
       }
       return false;
      }
```

```html
<body>
  
    <tr>
      <td valign="top">
        <form onsubmit="javascript:return voeruit();">
        <table summary="">
         <tr>
          <td>nieuw prijs</td>
                <td><input id="invoer2" value="" /></td>
                <td id="fout2"><td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
             <td>bouwjaar</td>
                <td><input id="invoer1" value="" /></td>
                <td id="fout1"><td>
            </tr>
            
        </table>
        </form>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td  valign="top">
         <button onclick="javascript:voeruit();">Voer uit</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <p id="uitkomst"></p>
  </table>
  </body>
```

Comment: `<form onsubmit="javascript:return voeruit();">` Unless something has changed recently, you should not have `javascript:` here.

Comment: When/where is the Javascript loaded? If it's in a `document.ready()` block, or something similar, those functions won't be defined outside the block.

Comment: Also you need an extra `}` to close off your `foutcontrole1` function\

Comment: and your table syntax is just wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Your javascript is invalid - `function foutcontrole1(foutje)` had no closing bracket, you should add another one `}` before `function berekenen()`